# Why sum of this process CPU(%) is not equal to total cpu(%) utilisation in top output

Tags: cpu, monitor, top

[image]

In the attached image of top command output, you can see the idle is 53.3% means CPU utilization is 52.7% but, sum of CPU% of all the process listed (Image cropped for CPU% > 0.0) is more than the total utilized (46.7%=100%-53.3%). The process 1954 here is bound to CPU11, and only this process is running on CPU11.
The fluctuations in CPU11 are significant, sometimes exceeding 16% of processes 1954 and sometimes falling below 20% of processes 1954. But often the difference is not significant, within 5%.

Comment: Top screenshots are momentary snapshots, not a "realtime" tracker. Don't expect the numbers to completely line up all the time.

Comment: Toggle the `Irix` mode by pressing I  (that makes it `Solaris Mode` )  " CPU percentage is calculated as a fraction of  total  available computing resources.  Hence on a multiprocessor machine a single threaded process can  never  consume  cpu  time  in excess  of 1 divided by the number of processors.  For example, on a 4 processor machine,  a  single  threaded  process will  never  show a cpu percentage higher than 25%.  The CPU percentage  column  will  always  total  approximately 100, regardless of the number of processors"

Comment: The fluctuations in CPU11 are significant, sometimes exceeding 16% of processes 1954 and sometimes falling below 20% of processes 1954. But often the difference is not significant, within 5%.